# How can I detect a mouse hover through another element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I have a area map where i show arrows if an area is hovered (JavaScript).
As you can see in the snippets there is "Kinderland" and "Spacecenter".
What I'm trying to do is that if you hover "Kinderland" and the "Spacecenter" arrow is in front of it (snippet 3) that the "Kinderland" arrow appears.

[image]

Here is a JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/rjq9pu6L/17/

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="de">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>

<style>
.none {
display: none;
}

#mapMainWrap {
width: 360px;
height: 150px;
background-image:url(https://i.postimg.cc/rpskZ4GZ/map.png);
}

.map {
z-index:50;
}

.maptrans {
z-index:30;
}

.mapMainArrow {
z-index:10;
}

#mapMainArrows {
width:201px;
height:22px;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
}

#mapMainArrows.mapMainArea1Arrow {
top:70px;
left:60px;
}

#mapMainArrows.mapMainArea2Arrow {
top:70px;
left:190px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="mapMainWrap">

  <div id="mapMainArrows">
    <img id="mapMainArea1Arrow" class="none mapMainArrow" src="https://i.postimg.cc/wMyQj9KQ/area1-ar.png" width="201" height="22" alt="Area 1">
    <img id="mapMainArea2Arrow" class="none mapMainArrow" src="https://i.postimg.cc/Qdb4PxjF/area2-ar.png" width="201" height="22" alt="Area 2">
  </div>

  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/ZqNmpdrG/maptrans.png" class="maptrans" width="360" height="150" alt="Map" usemap="#mapmain">
  <map name="mapmain" class="map">
      <area id="mapMainArea1" alt="Area 1" href="javascript:void(0)" coords="60,3,8,46,3,135,23,146,86,148,91,105,133,94,137,7" shape="poly">
      <area id="mapMainArea2" alt="Area 2" href="javascript:void(0)" coords="167,26,163,30,170,37,169,68,151,107,185,123,219,51,196,37" shape="poly">
  </map>

</div>

<script>
const mapMainArrows = document.getElementById('mapMainArrows');
const mapMainArrow = document.getElementsByClassName('mapMainArrow');
var imapMainArrow;
function hideMapMainArrow () {
  for (imapMainArrow = 0; imapMainArrow < mapMainArrow.length; imapMainArrow++) {
    mapMainArrow[imapMainArrow].classList.add("none");
  }
}

// Area 1
const mapMainArea1 = document.getElementById('mapMainArea1');
const mapMainArea1Arrow = document.getElementById('mapMainArea1Arrow');
mapMainArea1.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  hideMapMainArrow();
  mapMainArrows.className = "";
  mapMainArrows.classList.add("mapMainArea1Arrow");
  mapMainArea1Arrow.classList.remove("none");
}, false);

// Area 2
const mapMainArea2 = document.getElementById('mapMainArea2');
const mapMainArea2Arrow = document.getElementById('mapMainArea2Arrow');
mapMainArea2.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  hideMapMainArrow();
  mapMainArrows.className = "";
  mapMainArrows.classList.add("mapMainArea2Arrow");
  mapMainArea2Arrow.classList.remove("none");
}, false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i think you need the mouse to look like a pointer not an arrow, in this case you would need to add some CSS code like .pointer {cursor: pointer;}

check the URL below: 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_cursor

Comment: @Midz Elwekil as you can see in the screenshot, it is a pointer.

Comment: @Sumit Ridhal did make a JSFiddle

Comment: I would look at using the CSS option `pointer-events: none;` on your arrows. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't need to be able to click on anything inside the arrows:

You use the [CSS rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) `pointer-events: none;` on the arrows, this will prevent the arrows from catching the event and will allow it to pass through to the map underneath (And trigger your `mouseover` event listener)

The only thing I've changed from your snippet is the CSS for `#mapMainArrows`

```js
const mapMainArrows = document.getElementById('mapMainArrows');
const mapMainArrow = document.getElementsByClassName('mapMainArrow');
var imapMainArrow;

function hideMapMainArrow() {
  for (imapMainArrow = 0; imapMainArrow < mapMainArrow.length; imapMainArrow++) {
    mapMainArrow[imapMainArrow].classList.add("none");
  }
}

// Area 1
const mapMainArea1 = document.getElementById('mapMainArea1');
const mapMainArea1Arrow = document.getElementById('mapMainArea1Arrow');
mapMainArea1.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  hideMapMainArrow();
  mapMainArrows.className = "";
  mapMainArrows.classList.add("mapMainArea1Arrow");
  mapMainArea1Arrow.classList.remove("none");
}, false);

// Area 2
const mapMainArea2 = document.getElementById('mapMainArea2');
const mapMainArea2Arrow = document.getElementById('mapMainArea2Arrow');
mapMainArea2.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  hideMapMainArrow();
  mapMainArrows.className = "";
  mapMainArrows.classList.add("mapMainArea2Arrow");
  mapMainArea2Arrow.classList.remove("none");
}, false);
```

```css
.none {
  display: none;
}

#mapMainWrap {
  width: 360px;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/rpskZ4GZ/map.png);
}

.map {
  z-index: 50;
}

.maptrans {
  z-index: 30;
}

.mapMainArrow {
  z-index: 10;
}

#mapMainArrows {
  width: 201px;
  height: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#mapMainArrows.mapMainArea1Arrow {
  top: 70px;
  left: 60px;
}

#mapMainArrows.mapMainArea2Arrow {
  top: 70px;
  left: 190px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mapMainWrap">

  <div id="mapMainArrows">
    <img id="mapMainArea1Arrow" class="none mapMainArrow" src="https://i.postimg.cc/wMyQj9KQ/area1-ar.png" width="201" height="22" alt="Area 1">
    <img id="mapMainArea2Arrow" class="none mapMainArrow" src="https://i.postimg.cc/Qdb4PxjF/area2-ar.png" width="201" height="22" alt="Area 2">
  </div>

  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/ZqNmpdrG/maptrans.png" class="maptrans" width="360" height="150" alt="Map" usemap="#mapmain">
  <map name="mapmain" class="map">
      <area id="mapMainArea1" alt="Area 1" href="javascript:void(0)" coords="60,3,8,46,3,135,23,146,86,148,91,105,133,94,137,7" shape="poly">
      <area id="mapMainArea2" alt="Area 2" href="javascript:void(0)" coords="167,26,163,30,170,37,169,68,151,107,185,123,219,51,196,37" shape="poly">
  </map>

</div>
```

Comment: thank you. It also works without the z-index's and the transparent layer is not needed.